# Horde initial Administrator

Tags: php, debian, horde

I've got a problem after installing Horde Groupware on my Debian-System. The installation went well. Now I want to login as admin to finalize configuration but I don't get how to configure the admin account.
I researched my problem and I found some answers so that I know that I have to adjust the config.php-file on this row:

```
$conf['auth']['admins'] = array();
```

But I still don't know which values I have to insert in the array. The Horde-Groupware-System is completely fresh installed. So there doesn't exist any Horde-User.
When I interpret some answers correctly I have to insert my Debian-User in the Array but I don't get in which format? With domainname? With complete domain? With systemname? The Horde Documentation is there a little unspecific or I'm just dumb as hell. ;-)
Maybe someone can help me and know what I have to insert.
Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$conf['auth']['admins'] = array('admin1@mydomain.com','admin2@mydomain.com');
```

in config/conf.php

Answer (score 0):

This config setting only makes an existing account be an admin.

If you require to inject a "first account" into an empty backend (like SQL), you might want to configure Horde first to use the auto driver:

## The manual / hard way

Copy conf.php.dist to conf.php
https://github.com/horde/base/blob/master/config/conf.php.dist

Or add to an existing conf.php these lines on the bottom.

```
$conf['auth']['admins'] = array('administrator');
$conf['auth']['driver'] = 'auto';
$conf['auth']['params'] = array('username' => 'administrator');
```

Then visit horde via browser. You will be auto-logged in as "administrator".

While logged in, change to the "SQL" backend (or whatever you use).

You are still logged in as an administrator. Go to user admin screen and add a first user and password.

Once the user is in the db, change the "administrator" configuration to include this user.

```
$conf['auth']['admins'] = array('administrator', 'myusername');
```

Then log out and log back in using the new user/pw.

## Ways around this situation:

- Use an export of an existing user DB.
- Use the "groupware" bundle, it comes with a setup script that injects the first user for you.
- with the upcoming Horde 6, you can use the hordectl tool to inject initial users.